# Table View Cell gets Sigabrt Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

**Issue:** I connected a Static Table View cell with a ViewController with a `Push (Non-Adaptive Selection Segue)`

When I ran the app and **pressed the first Table View Cell**, I immediately got the error: `Thread 1 Signal Sigbrt` on the main.m

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

*(Note: There is no code that comes with this)*

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Is your `Table View Controller` present in navigation stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed the table view controller within a navigation controller in order to push views onto the navigation stack. If you don't want to use navigation controllers, you can do `presentViewControllerAnimated:` instead.

**EDIT:**

You can easily embed a view controller in a navigation controller using IB, like shown below (remember to select the view controller you want to be embedded):

[image]

Comment: But I have multiple other viewcontrollers, how can I embed it?

Comment: doesn't it have to be the first?

Comment: So embed the first, then present each consecutive view controller by pushing it onto the navigation stack (like you were trying to do in your question).

Comment: I mean, doesn't the navigation controller have to be at the **VERY** beginning of the storyboard

Comment: No, you can use a navigation controller wherever you like within your app